# Use single input field to upload video/image and display a image/video preview in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to build a input field that can accept both image as well as video uploads. I am able to successfully upload the files. But, its giving me error on showing the preview. Below is the code I wrote for this. On using ternary operator to check if file type is equal to "image" it should show img component on true value and on false should display video component. But somehow the ternary operator is always going to 2nd condition(when false) even if 1st is true. If I put img tag in true condition and video tag on false, when I upload image/video in both condition video tag is shown. Similarly, if I put video tag in true and img tag on false, when I upload image/video in both condition img tag is shown. Its never going to 1st condition(true). Whats the error ?
I have even tried to create file_type variable using useState but that also doesnt work.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { CgAttachment } from "react-icons/cg";
import { MdDeleteForever } from 'react-icons/md';

const ChatFooter = () => {
  var file, file_ext, file_path, file_type, file_name;
  const [attachmentPreview, setAttachmentPreview] = useState(null);
  const [attachment, setAttachment] = useState(null); 

  const onFileChange = (e) => {
     const file = e.target.files[0];

     file_ext; //# will extract file extension
     file_type = file.type; file_name = file.name;
     file_path = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);
    
     //# get file extension (eg: "jpg" or "jpeg" or "webp" etc)
     file_ext = file_name.toLowerCase();
     file_ext = file_ext.substr( (file_ext.lastIndexOf(".")+1), (file_ext.length - 
      file_ext.lastIndexOf(".")) );
    
     //# get file type (eg: "image" or "video")
     file_type = file_type.toLowerCase();
     file_type = file_type.substr( 0, file_type.indexOf("/") );

    setAttachment(file);
    e.target.value="";

    if(file) {
        const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        setAttachmentPreview(blobUrl);
    }   
  }  

  return (
    {
      attachmentPreview && (
       <div className='absolute w-[100px] h-[100px] bottom-16 left-0 bg-c1 p-2   
        rounded-md'>
           //error is in below condition
           file_type === "image" ?
           <img src={attachmentPreview} alt='Attachment Preview' />
            :
           <video width="400" controls>
              <source src={attachmentPreview} type="video/mp4">
           </video>
           <div className='absolute -right-2 -top-2 cursor-pointer w-6 h-6 rounded-  
               full bg-red-500 flex justify-center items-center'
               onClick={() => {
                  setAttachment(null);
                  setAttachmentPreview(null);
               }}
           >
             <MdDeleteForever size={14} /> //delete icon for deleting preview
           </div> 
       </div>
      )
    }
    <div className='shrink-0'>
      <input
        type='file'
        id='fileUploader'
        className='hidden'
        onChange={onFileChange}
        accept='image/*, video/*'
      />
      <label htmlFor='fileUploader'>
        <CgAttachment size={20} /> //pin icon for uploading files
      </label>
    </div>
 )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function of setting the `attachmentPreview` state seems to be working fine, could setting the file type along with it, like:

```js
setAttachmentPreview({
  blob: blobUrl,
  type: file_type,
});
```

And then adjust your rendering as follows:

```
{attachmentPreview.type === 'image' ? (
  <img src={attachmentPreview.blob} alt="Attachment Preview" />
) : (
  <video width="400" controls>
    <source src={attachmentPreview.blob} type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
)}
```

```js
const { useState } = React;

/*** `react-icons` code START **/
const DefaultContext = {
  color: undefined,
  size: undefined,
  className: undefined,
  style: undefined,
  attr: undefined,
};
const iconContext_1 = {
  IconContext: React.createContext && React.createContext(DefaultContext),
};
var __assign =
  (this && this.__assign) ||
  function () {
    __assign =
      Object.assign ||
      function (t) {
        for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
          s = arguments[i];
          for (var p in s) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p)) t[p] = s[p];
        }
        return t;
      };
    return __assign.apply(this, arguments);
  };
var __rest =
  (this && this.__rest) ||
  function (s, e) {
    var t = {};
    for (var p in s)
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p) && e.indexOf(p) < 0) t[p] = s[p];
    if (s != null && typeof Object.getOwnPropertySymbols === 'function')
      for (var i = 0, p = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(s); i < p.length; i++) {
        if (e.indexOf(p[i]) < 0 && Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(s, p[i]))
          t[p[i]] = s[p[i]];
      }
    return t;
  };
function IconBase(props) {
  var elem = function (conf) {
    var attr = props.attr,
      size = props.size,
      title = props.title,
      svgProps = __rest(props, ['attr', 'size', 'title']);
    var computedSize = size || conf.size || '1em';
    var className;
    if (conf.className) className = conf.className;
    if (props.className) className = (className ? className + ' ' : '') + props.className;
    return React.createElement(
      'svg',
      __assign(
        { stroke: 'currentColor', fill: 'currentColor', strokeWidth: '0' },
        conf.attr,
        attr,
        svgProps,
        {
          className: className,
          style: __assign(__assign({ color: props.color || conf.color }, conf.style), props.style),
          height: computedSize,
          width: computedSize,
          xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
        }
      ),
      title && React.createElement('title', null, title),
      props.children
    );
  };
  return iconContext_1.IconContext !== undefined
    ? React.createElement(iconContext_1.IconContext.Consumer, null, function (conf) {
        return elem(conf);
      })
    : elem(iconContext_1.DefaultContext);
}

function Tree2Element(tree) {
  return (
    tree &&
    tree.map(function (node, i) {
      return React.createElement(
        node.tag,
        __assign({ key: i }, node.attr),
        Tree2Element(node.child)
      );
    })
  );
}
function GenIcon(data) {
  return function (props) {
    return React.createElement(
      IconBase,
      __assign({ attr: __assign({}, data.attr) }, props),
      Tree2Element(data.child)
    );
  };
}

function CgAttachment(props) {
  return GenIcon({
    tag: 'svg',
    attr: { viewBox: '0 0 24 24', fill: 'none' },
    child: [
      {
        tag: 'path',
        attr: {
          d: 'M14 0C16.7614 0 19 2.23858 19 5V17C19 20.866 15.866 24 12 24C8.13401 24 5 20.866 5 17V9H7V17C7 19.7614 9.23858 22 12 22C14.7614 22 17 19.7614 17 17V5C17 3.34315 15.6569 2 14 2C12.3431 2 11 3.34315 11 5V17C11 17.5523 11.4477 18 12 18C12.5523 18 13 17.5523 13 17V6H15V17C15 18.6569 13.6569 20 12 20C10.3431 20 9 18.6569 9 17V5C9 2.23858 11.2386 0 14 0Z',
          fill: 'currentColor',
        },
      },
    ],
  })(props);
}
function MdDeleteForever(props) {
  return GenIcon({
    tag: 'svg',
    attr: { viewBox: '0 0 24 24' },
    child: [
      { tag: 'path', attr: { fill: 'none', d: 'M0 0h24v24H0z' } },
      { tag: 'path', attr: { fill: 'none', d: 'M0 0h24v24H0V0z' } },
      {
        tag: 'path',
        attr: {
          d: 'M6 19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7H6v12zm2.46-7.12l1.41-1.41L12 12.59l2.12-2.12 1.41 1.41L13.41 14l2.12 2.12-1.41 1.41L12 15.41l-2.12 2.12-1.41-1.41L10.59 14l-2.13-2.12zM15.5 4l-1-1h-5l-1 1H5v2h14V4z',
        },
      },
    ],
  })(props);
}
/*** `react-icons` code END **/

const ChatFooter = () => {
  var file, file_ext, file_path, file_type, file_name;
  const [attachmentPreview, setAttachmentPreview] = useState(null);
  const [attachment, setAttachment] = useState(null);

  const onFileChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    file_ext; //# will extract file extension
    file_type = file.type;
    file_name = file.name;
    file_path = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);

    //# get file extension (eg: "jpg" or "jpeg" or "webp" etc)
    file_ext = file_name.toLowerCase();
    file_ext = file_ext.substr(
      file_ext.lastIndexOf('.') + 1,
      file_ext.length - file_ext.lastIndexOf('.')
    );

    //# get file type (eg: "image" or "video")
    file_type = file_type.toLowerCase();
    file_type = file_type.substr(0, file_type.indexOf('/'));

    setAttachment(file);
    e.target.value = '';

    if (file) {
      const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      setAttachmentPreview({
        blob: blobUrl,
        type: file_type,
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {attachmentPreview && (
        <div
          className="absolute w-[100px] h-[100px] bottom-16 left-0 bg-c1 p-2   
        rounded-md"
        >
          {attachmentPreview.type === 'image' ? (
            <img src={attachmentPreview.blob} alt="Attachment Preview" />
          ) : (
            <video width="400" controls>
              <source src={attachmentPreview.blob} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
          )}
          <div
            className="absolute -right-2 -top-2 cursor-pointer w-6 h-6 rounded-  
               full bg-red-500 flex justify-center items-center"
            onClick={() => {
              setAttachment(null);
              setAttachmentPreview(null);
            }}
          >
            <MdDeleteForever size={14} />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      <div className="shrink-0">
        <input
          type="file"
          id="fileUploader"
          className="hidden"
          onChange={onFileChange}
          accept="image/*, video/*"
        />
        <label htmlFor="fileUploader">
          <CgAttachment size={20} />
        </label>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<ChatFooter />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```